# Vim + zencoding: Both tab and <c-y> expand tags

Tags: vim, emmet

I have gVim 7.2 and recently added Zencoding to help with my web programming.

I changed the keymapping from `<c-y>,` to `<c-y>` for expanding tags.  Then, while editing my files in Vim's insert mode, I noticed that my tab key no longer works.  Instead, the tab now performs the exact same function as `<c-y>`.  I want `<c-y>` to continue to perform the expand function and tab should just insert a tab.  How do I do this?

Comment: Did you possibly make a typo and mean you changed it to `<C-i>`?  If so, the behavior you speak of would make sense because `<Tab>` and `<C-i>` are equivalent.